# Joining specific bytes data in python3.6

Tags: python, string, unicode, byte

```
a = 192
b = 168

packet = []
packet.append(bytes([a]))
packet.append(bytes([b]))
```

#Since the packet has only bytes data for numeral range 0-255 how can I convert it to str so that I can perform join

```
packet = ''.join(packet)
```

Comment: Try `b''.join(packet)` or `b''.join(packet).decode('cp1252')`. (Note that `cp1252` is merely a guess.)

Answer (score 1):

A list of byte strings must use a byte string with the join. e.g. `b''.join(packet)`.  But considering that `bytes()` can be constructed from a list of byte-ranged integers, just convert later:

```
>>> packet=[]
>>> packet.append(192)
>>> packet.append(168)
>>> bytes(packet)
b'\xc0\xa8'
```